# Mouseover UL Child Nodes Not Right

Tags: javascript

This works in IE8, but not IE9, FF8 or FF9.  It seems like something that should work though.

The intended behavior:  When you scroll over the LI, it should pop an alert with that node's LI id.

The actual behavior, when you scroll over the 2nd element (node[1]), it alerts the id for node[0].  When you scroll over node[0] or node[2], the alert gives an undefined.

Can anyone help me make sense of this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.outputUl{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;   
}
.outputLi {

}
.outputLiSelect {
    background-color: #069; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="outputUl" id="meganFox">
    <li id="li1"
        class="outputLi" 
        onmouseover="setSelect(1);">Frank</li>
    <li id="li2"
        class="outputLi" 
        onmouseover="setSelect(2);">Bob</li>
    <li id="li3"
        class="outputLi" 
        onmouseover="setSelect(3);">Jeff</li>
</ul>

<script language="javascript">
function setSelect( num ){
    var nodes = document.getElementById('meganFox').childNodes;
    num = num - 1;
    nodes[num].className = 'outputLiSelect';
    alert( 'id '+nodes[num].id );
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The childNodes collection includes empty text nodes on some browsers.  You'll need to loop through them and only consider the nodes that have nodeType = 1 (HTML elements).

I have taken your code above and added a new method `getChildElements()` which does just that.  Try it and see whether it fixes the problem.

That said, Eugen Rieck's solution is more elegant-- he passes the affected element directly to the `setSelect` method rather than fiddling with indexes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
    .outputUl { margin: 0; padding: 0px; list-style: none; width: 200px; }
    .outputLi {  }
    .outputLiSelect { background-color: #069; cursor: pointer; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="outputUl" id="meganFox">
        <li id="li1" class="outputLi" onmouseover="setSelect(1);">Frank</li>
        <li id="li2" class="outputLi" onmouseover="setSelect(2);">Bob</li>
        <li id="li3" class="outputLi" onmouseover="setSelect(3);">Jeff</li>
    </ul>
    <script language="javascript">
        function setSelect( num )
        {
            var nodes = getChildElements(document.getElementById('meganFox'));
            num = num - 1;
            nodes[num].className = 'outputLiSelect';
            alert( 'id '+nodes[num].id );
        }

        function getChildElements(parentNode)
        {
            var list = [];
            if (parentNode.childNodes)
            {
                var nodes = parentNode.childNodes;
                for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++)
                {
                    // only include nodes that are HTML elements
                    if (nodes[i].nodeType == 1)
                        list.push(nodes[i]);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code above is all inclusive.  I don't think any of them are empty?

Comment: phpmeh—many browsers insert empty text nodes to replace whitespace between elements in the markup. And some browsers don't. Do `alert(nodes.length);` and you will see that there are more than 3 in most browsers (though likely not in IE).

Comment: @phpmeh - I have added example code to my answer to illustrate what I meant.  The `<ul>`; has 7 children: 3 visible `<li>` elements and 4 empty text nodes interspersed between them.  ( `<ul>(text)<li></li>(text)<li></li>(text)<li></li>(text)</ul>` )

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
onmouseover="setSelect(this);"
```

and

```
function setSelect(node) {
  node.className='outputLiSelect';
  alert('id '+node.id);
}
```

Comment: This worked.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with Brian Rogers' empty text nodees above.

Answer (score 0):

In your code. nodes start from 1. so don't use num = num-1;

Comment: The node starts from 0.  node[0], node[1], node[2].  If that wasn't the case, it wouldn't work in IE8.  I'm using 1 for the setSelect function because of other requirements in the code that are not relevant here.